# refactoring code for better recursion

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am trying to write some code that will look into a pdf file and call the Process method (to find a qr code image in the pdf) if not found then it rotates the file and runs the Process method again. Currently I don't think that what I have actually checks the file after being rotated but checks the same original file in its original format. How can I pass in the rotated image properly into the Process method:

```
  using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
                {
                    var bandImg = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);

                    Bitmap result = fullImg;
                    if (Process(bandImg) == null)
                    {
                          fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                          bandImg = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                        if (Process(bandImg) == null)
                        {
                             fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                             bandImg = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                            if (Process(bandImg) == null)
                            {
                                fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                                bandImg = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                                //Process(bandImg);
                                string QRinfo = Process(bandImg);
                                MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);
                                string[] qcode = QRinfo.Split('/');
                                string gid = qcode[qcode.Count() - 1];
                                Guid pgGuid = new Guid(gid);
                                var ar = dc.Assessments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == pgGuid);
                                if (ar != null)
                                {
                                    var p = inputDocument.Pages[pg];
                                    string opdName = FILESTORELOCATION + pgGuid.ToString() + ".pdf";
                                    PdfDocument opd = new PdfDocument(opdName);
                                    opd.Pages.Add(p);
                                    opd.Close();

                                    ar.StoragePath = opdName;
                                    ar.LastUploadedDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                    ar.UploadedByUserID = uploadingUser;
                                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

**Process Method:**

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var reader = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader();

    try
    {
        LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
        var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        return reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There seem to be no recursion in code you've posted...

Comment: You're passing `bandImg` to `Process()`, but you never update `bandImg` after you've rotated the PDF; have you tried doing the `bandImg = fullImg.Clone(...` call after rotating and passing *that* value?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that is because i wanted help in converting my if statements into a proper recursive call after rotating the image

Comment: @newfurniturey when i tried `bandImg = fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);` i get the error message `Cannot implicitly convert type void to type system.drawing.bitmap`

Comment: @Amina Yeah, that's why I said do the `bandImg = fullImg.Clone()` call, not `bandImg = fullImg.RotateFlip()`. you have to clone the image *after* you've rotated it (or, at least try - not sure if it'll work or not).

Comment: for what purpose of flip call 3 time ? angle 270 is angle -90 exact.

Comment: @Prashantp the purpose is that the QR code will always be on the top left corner in a pdf - and i want to check the corner and if not found rotate document until the qr code is in the upper left corner and save the document because witht he qr code on top left corner the document is in proper required format.

Comment: @newfurniturey i just tried it but when i still look at the output saved file it is not the rotated one.

Comment: @Amina When you finally get to the "saving" portion of the code (which should actually be outside of all of the `if`-statements), you're using `var p = inputDocument.Pages[pg]; opd.Pages.Add(p);`. I'm not really sure the exact purpose of your code, but this looks like it saves the original page? Perhaps you mean to use `opd.Pages.Add(fullImg);`?

Comment: @newfurniturey so if i ignore the if statement `if(ar != null)` how can i save the image of what i just rotated? I tried `bandImg.Save(fileName)` but didn't work

Comment: @Amina Did you try `opd.Pages.Add(fullImg);` instead of `opd.Pages.Add(p);`?

Comment: @newfurniturey yes and i got the following error when i build ` cannot convert from system.drawing.bitmap to pdfsharp.pdf.pdfpage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a recursive solution check this (untested code of course):

```
string ReadQrCode(Bitmap img, int n = 0) {
    if(n == 4) return null;

    var bandImg = img.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), 
        img.PixelFormat);
    string text = Process(bandImg);

    if(text == null) {
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        text = ReadQrCode(img, n + 1);
    }

    return Text;
}
```

Example:

```
string qrCode;
using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif)) {        
    qrCode = ReadQrCode(bandImg);
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**
Recursion is not needed to solve this kind of problem actually, indeed, as  Alexei Levenkov pointed out in his comment below, a loop is much easier and clear:

```
string text = null;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var bandImg = img.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), 
            img.PixelFormat);
    text = Process(bandImg)

    if(text != null) break;
    else img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
}
```

In the recursive solution n behaves like the counter does in the loop, this means that recursion will have a depth of four calls (at most) just like the loop will iterate four times (at most).

Comment: Thanks i will try to work this and see how it will turn it. Also i have just updated my post with the full code usage i am using.

Comment: I guess bandImg is not the full image but a small top-left portion of it. Your code seems to rotate the portion and not the full image.

Comment: I might be wrong but probably OP wants to rotate the fullImage and see if the QR code is in the top-left corner. If not, try to rotate by 90 degrees (full image) and then see if QR code is on the top-left corner and so on. I agree the details are not clear from the question.

Comment: @publicgk: you're right, probably the qr code reader deals with the rotation of the qr itself

Comment: +1. for recursive solution as requested. Also simple loop may be more readable/easier to understand correctness in real code.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how this is recursive- i feel like i am not really getting it. is the `n+1` the part in which it will go back to the top and check the corner after rotating?

Comment: @BlackBear - i think when i rotate i should rotate the full original image and not the clone because the clone is only looking at a specific piece of the page and will only rotate that piece. correct? I really appreciate the clarification.